# C++ IF Statement inside a function issue

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble with a basic program for a C++ class. In the following function, i have debugged and the arguments being passed in are correct, however the if statement below is returning 'F' for the first element of the array I pass in, and the second and each thereafter score I pass in is being returned as 'D'.

When I do the math out, my data set should hit each part of the if statement at least once, however im guessing maybe my PEMDAS is off?

Here is the if statement:

```
char grade(double score, double m, double s) {

    if (score < (m - 1.5 * s)) {
        return 'F';
    }
    if ((m - (1.5*s)) <= score < (m - (0.5 * s))) {
        return 'D';
    }
    if ((m - (0.5 * s)) <= score < (m + (0.5 * s))) {
        return 'C';
    }
    if ((m + (0.5 * s)) <= score < (m + (1.5 * s))) {
        return 'B';
    }
    if ((m + (1.5 * s)) <= score) {
        return 'A';
    }
    else {
        return 'X';
    }
}
```

Comment: `[...] <= score < [...]` comparisons don't work that way in c++.

Comment: `A < B < C` ( or any comparison operator, not just `<`) doesn't do what you think it does, in C++. [See this link for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What would be my best bet for this situation?

Comment: two seperate comparisons and a `&&`

Comment: You're a god, I remember the && now but just figured I could compare as I did above. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: When you write `x < y < z`, it is actually calculated as `(x < y) < z`. If `x` is less than `y`, the expression `(x < y)` returns `true`, which is converted to `1` in arithmetic and comparison expressions. If `x` is no less than `y`, `(x < y)` returns `false`, which is converted to `0`. So your expression becomes, effectively, `1 < z` and `0 < z`, respectively. Use `(x < y) && (y < z)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

An expression like:

```
a < b < c
```

does not do what you think it does. It actually evaluates as:

```
(a < b) < c
```

where `a < b` is a truth value giving `0` for false and `1` for true`. Then *that* value is used in the rest of the expression.

By way of example, the expression `100 < 200 < 42` will be true because `100 < 200` evaluates to `1`, which is definitely less than `42`.

Instead you should be using something like:

```
(a < b) && (b < c)
```

---

In any case, you can clean up that code quite a bit by realising that:

1. The construct `if (condition) return else ...` is totally unnecessary - the `return` means that the rest of the code will execute only if `condition` is false, rendering the `else` superfluous.
2. Because your ranges are mutually exclusive, the checks can be simplified. In other words, no need to check if `(m - (1.5*s)) <= score` in the `D` case since, if that weren't true, the code would already have returned `F`.
3. It is currently impossible to get an `X` grade since there is no score that doesn't get captured one of the `if` statements, excepting *possibly* some edge cases like `NaN` but I'm going to assume you're not worried about that.

With those points in mind, the code can be simplified to:

```
char grade(double score, double m, double s) {
    if (score < m - 1.5 * s) return 'F';
    if (score < m - 0.5 * s) return 'D';
    if (score < m + 0.5 * s) return 'C';
    if (score < m + 1.5 * s) return 'B';
    return 'A';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to know the input data values to have a complete understanding, however as others have pointed out, comparisons don't work like that in C++.

Take this comparison:
(m - (1.5*s)) <= score < (m - (0.5 * s))

What this is doing is first evaluating:
(m - (1.5*s)) <= score

Due to the first if statement failing, this will always evaluate to true.  In C++, boolean values are integers, and true is usually represented by "1" (in practice it doesn't have to be, and can be represented by any non-zero number, but I think in this specific case it's being set to 1).

Then it's evaluating:
1 < (m - (0.5*s))

Which I'm assuming always returns true given your values of "m" and "s".

What you should be doing instead is using a compound statement:

if (m - 1.5*s <= score && score < m - 0.5*s)

(you can keep the parentheses if you like, but they're unnecessary here due to C++'s [operator precedence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence))

Comment: Then don't post an answer, then.

Comment: The [conversion from bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) *always* maps `true` to 1.  And `&&` doesn’t make a compound *statement*.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop all of the lower-bound comparisons (which, as others have said, do not do what you thought): if any of them don’t apply, you would already have returned one of the lower scores.